# MongoID chaining and scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I use MongoID throughout my Rails project. I basically had a query like

```
def available_skus
  skus.is_active.in_stock.order_by({:discount => :desc}, {:quantity => :desc})
end
```

It refers partially to the scope inside my `Sku` model which's an embedded collection.

I've the following scopes in there

```
scope :is_active, -> { where(:status => true) }
scope :in_stock,  -> { any_of({:unlimited => true}, {:quantity.gt => 0}) }
scope :can_buy,   -> { is_active.in_stock }
```

I created `can_buy` to avoid repetition since I use `is_active.in_stock` together very often and it has a specific meaning ; *you can buy this sku*.

In short, if I write `skus.is_active.in_stock` it works perfectly and get some results, but if I use **`skus.can_buy`** then it gives no result.

I don't understand the behaviour here. Isn't `can_buy` a simple shortcut to the two other scopes ?

Comment: you can check the difference by running these in console: 1. `skus.is_active.in_stock.selector` and 2. `skus.can_buy.selector`

Comment: Note the `$and` and `$or` statements carefully.